# How do I alter this code to make it work in IE8?

Tags: angularjs

This works in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE8. What changes do I make to make it work in IE8? Please paste the altered code in your answer. Thank you! :)

```
<html ng-app>
     <body>
       <div>
        {{ 3 + 2 }}
       </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: Could someone please paste an example that works? Yes I could read the manual and struggle with it - I've already done that. I'd rather just see an actual working example to see exactly what I'm typing wrong. :) Thanks.

Comment: BKM example should work. You might need to add a meta tag at the top of your html to force it to render the page in IE8 compatability instead of an older one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this;

```
<html >
     <body ng-app id="ng-app">
       <div>
        {{ 3 + 2 }}
       </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I haven't been able to find an actual working example of Angular in IE8 at all. And I've really tried to find one! :)

Comment: We need to enter <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"> in the head to make it work, just like yuvi said.